# Trying to pass a Binding<Bool> variable into a view?

Tags: view, binding, swiftui, data-transfer

so I have a binding variable that is declared in a class with:

```
@Binding var variableName: Bool
```

I am returning a view when a certain function is called. I'd like to pass the annotation into that view with:

```
return CustomView(variableName: $variableName)
```

Is this correct? I'm not sure. Also, inside the view itself, I'm not entirely sure how to do the initialization properly. The end goal is to be able to access the value of variableName from the functions of the view. Anyways, I tried declaring the following inside the CustomView class:

```
@Binding var variableName: Bool
```

For the initialization, I wasn't sure if I should pass in the variable name into the arguments (and if I should, I wasn't sure how. I also didn't know if I should somehow initialize with self.variableName = value...Just to be clear, the goal is to access the value of variableName after initialization. If I can add any more code to make this more comprehensible, let me know!

Comment: The provided declarations by themselves are correct, but might not work due to called or inside code. Would you show demo code for issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really clear what you want to achieve, but have a look at the code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ParentView: View {

    @Binding var customVariable: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $customVariable) {
                Text("Show/Hide Custom View")
            }
            if $customVariable.wrappedValue {
                CustomView(customVariable: $customVariable)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomView: View {

    @Binding var customVariable: Bool

    init(customVariable: Binding<Bool>) { // You don't need an initializer here, it is just to demonstrate how you can use it for Binding values
        _customVariable = customVariable
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Custom View")
    }
}
```

However, a better way to coordinate the model and the view in SwiftUI can be illustrated as below:

```
import SwiftUI

class CustomModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var shouldShowCustomView: Bool = false
}    

struct ParentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model: CustomModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $model.shouldShowCustomView) {
                Text("Show/Hide Custom View")
            }
            if model.shouldShowCustomView {
                CustomView()
                    .environmentObject(model)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var model: CustomModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("Custom View")
    }
}
```

So, instead of `Binding`, you can use `ObservableObject` with `Published` values.

Comment: Oh, okay thank you! The first implementation worked but if you think the second implementation is cleaner, I'd like to like into it more. Do you have any resources for learning more about specifically using @Published variables and  the ObservableObject protocol together?

Comment: Ah great! So, if you have a complex model which includes more than a bool or an int, then creating a model as an ObservableObject makes more sense in which you can have Published values which work very similar to State variables. They are just wrapped in an ObservableObject so they can be passed to other views altogether. 
However, if you only need a simple variable in a view then State is better and you can pass the State to other views by using Binding.
An article here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-observedobject-to-manage-state-from-external-objects

Comment: Couple more sources:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject
https://medium.com/@shensheng/swiftui-difference-of-state-binding-environment-and-environmentobject-and-when-to-use-them-ff80699f45b7
And by the way if you are happy with the answer, you can select it as the correct answer :)